# How to determine why the remove event of backbone collection is triggered?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

Remove event on backbone collection is triggered when the model has been removed from the collection.

But I need to differentiate whether destroying the model triggers the remove event on collection or just removing the model from collection triggers the remove event on collection.

Comment: You could add `on("destroy")` event listener to model's initialize method, and catch `destroy` event.

Comment: @Vahan Yeah but I need the listener only at collection level. And in my case, there are chances for both **model's destroy** triggering remove event on collection and **removing model from collection** triggering remove event on collection. I need to differentiate both.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your question?

Comment: how is the model in your code gets destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to differentiate those two cases.  My recommendation would be to override the `remove` method yourself and have it trigger your own event(s):

```
var YourCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    remove: {
        this.trigger('aboutToRemovedViaRemoveMethod');
        // Call the original remove
        var removeResult = Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
        this.trigger('removedViaRemoveMethod');
        return removeResult;
    }
});
```

And then of course `destroy` you can already listen for separately, as it has its own event.